# java: input.next no longer accepting user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input, java-io

i fixed most of the new issues but now im getting an empty character literal and unclosed character literal error on line:    char a = input.next('');

Below is my new code but im not entirely sure how to fix this error.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
public class JesseSabatinihw {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char lottoGameSelection; // user inputs whether or not they want to play the Lottery Game
        int game; // user input of game 3, 4, or 5 as integer
        int times; // user input of times game is played as integer
        int randNum; // random number generator creates an integer
        int lotNum; //lottery number generated as an integer
        int sum = 0; // initializing the sum of all integers as 0 to start with

        System.out.println("Do you wish to make lottery game selections?");
        char a = input.next('');
        if(a == 'Y' || a =='y') {       
            System.out.println("Which lottery game do you want to play!");
            System.out.println("Enter 3 for Pick 3");
            System.out.println("Enter 4 for Pick 4");
            System.out.println("Enter 5 for Pick 5");
            game = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("How many games would you like to play? ");
            times = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Thank you! The numbers selected were: ");
            // generates random lottery number specific to the chosen game 3, 4, or 5 numbers per games specified by user input
            Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
                lotNum = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < game; j++) {
                    do {
                        randNum = (new java.util.Random()).nextInt(10); // calls on the java.util.Random class to randomly select number for game
                    // prevents the generation of duplicate numbers per game
                    } while (numbers.contains(randNum));
                    numbers.add(randNum);
                    lotNum = (lotNum * 10) + randNum; // selects random integers 0 - 9
                    System.out.print(randNum); // prints randomly generated number
                    sum += randNum; // adds all random numbers generated
                }
                numbers.clear(); // refreshes the number generator preventing duplication of numbers and preventing the code to stop if all int 0-9 are used previously
                System.out.println(); // prints each game on it's own line
            }
            System.out.println("Sum of the numbers of all games: " + sum); //prints the total of all randomly generated lottery numbers
        } else {
            if (a == 'N' || a == 'n'); {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Refrain from posting text as images. Stick to posting in text format for output/code/data.

Comment: `''` (two single quotes) is an empty character literal, and `"` (one double quote) is an unclosed string literal. Neither is valid Java. Presumably you mean `""` (two double quotes), but that won't work as a terminator in `Scanner.next()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Set to store numbers you already got and then redraw until you get a number that is not in the Set.

```
System.out.println("Thank you! The numbers selected were: ");
Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();
for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
  lotNum = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < game; j++) {
    do {
      randNum = (new java.util.Random()).nextInt(10);
    } while (numbers.contains(randNum));
    numbers.add(randNum);
    lotNum = (lotNum * 10) + randNum;
    System.out.print(randNum);
    sum += randNum;
  }
  numbers.clear();
  System.out.println();
}
```

I am not sure in what scope you want the numbers to be unique so maybe you have to pull the creation of the set inside the outer loop - or just call number.clear() when you want to reset it.

Comment: I will go ahead and test this out, but thank you for the response. I don't know if you were able to see my image which was an example output but basically, each line generates which ever game selected, so example if you chose game 3 and play it two times the output will look like this:

123
234 

what i want to prevent is duplicates per line. example:

223
445 etc....

hopefully your solution provided with prevent this so again I really appreciate the response!

Comment: so after editing my code and adding what you suggested, i get no duplicates, however due to the no duplicated it stops the code after all int 0-9 are used and doesnt print the sum so example:

game 3 5 games:

023
146
578
9

this would be the output and it would just stop there, so on one hand i dont get duplicates which is awesome but on the other it no longer does what i need it if the input requests the output to generate more than 0-9..... if that makes sense

Comment: Well you limit your random numbers to 0-9 and you do not want duplicates, so there is not way that you can generate more except you broaden the range of numbers the Random object gives you.

Comment: Oh wait I think I get what you are trying to say. I think you have to empty the Set after each game, so call numbers.clear() after the inner for-loop.
I updated my code.

Comment: that's awesome, I added the numbers.clear(); and it now works perfectly! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

so i finally fixed it and got it to work exactly the way i wanted
see below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class JesseSabatinihw2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char lottoGameSelection; // user inputs whether or not they want to play the Lottery Game
        int game; // user input of game 3, 4, or 5 as integer
        int times; // user input of times game is played as integer
        int randNum; // random number generator creates an integer
        int lotNum; //lottery number generated as an integer
        int sum = 0; // initializing the sum of all integers as 0 to start with

        System.out.println("Do you wish to make lottery game selections? Press Y or y for yes and N or n for no.");
        char a = input.next().trim().charAt(0);
        if(a == 'Y' || a == 'y') {       
            System.out.println("Which lottery game do you want to play!");
            System.out.println("Enter 3 for Pick 3");
            System.out.println("Enter 4 for Pick 4");
            System.out.println("Enter 5 for Pick 5");
            game = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("How many games would you like to play? ");
            times = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Thank you! The numbers selected were: ");
            // generates random lottery number specific to the chosen game 3, 4, or 5 numbers per games specified by user input
            Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
                lotNum = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j < game; j++) {
                    do {
                        randNum = (new java.util.Random()).nextInt(10); // calls on the java.util.Random class to randomly select number for game
                    // prevents the generation of duplicate numbers per game
                    } while (numbers.contains(randNum));
                    numbers.add(randNum);
                    lotNum = (lotNum * 10) + randNum; // selects random integers 0 - 9
                    System.out.print(randNum); // prints randomly generated number
                    sum += randNum; // adds all random numbers generated
                }
                numbers.clear(); // refreshes the number generator preventing duplication of numbers and preventing the code to stop if all int 0-9 are used previously
                System.out.println(); // prints each game on it's own line
            }
            System.out.println("Sum of the numbers of all games: " + sum); //prints the total of all randomly generated lottery numbers
        } else {
             if (a == 'N' || a == 'n'); {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```